# Android RxJava: Chaining two requests and doing some logic inbetween

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, flatmap

Hi i am trying to create a chain of network requests using flatmap but dont quite understand the process on how to do this.

The goal is to do this:

do networkRequest 1
once i get a result from networkRequestOne, do some bit of logic on that result and then execute the next networkRequestTwo and the call onSuccess with teh returned response value from networkRequestTwo.

current code:

```
delegator.requestOne(requestData)
                .flatMap ({  response ->
                    if(response.isSuccessful){
                        cookieStorage.saveSessionCookies(response.header(cookieStorage.COOKIE_HEADER_NAME)!!)
                    }
                    return delegator.requestTwo

                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(object : SingleObserver<ResponseTwo>() {
                    @Override
                    fun onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    fun onSuccess(responseTwo :ResponseTwo) {
                        callback.onSuccess(responseTwo)
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }
                });
```

both delegator.requestOne and delegator.requestTwo both hooked up to a retrofit call that returns  a Single observable

Comment: I would put `saveSessionCookies` into a `doAfterSuccess()` since it's a side effect. But other than that, what is wrong with the current implementation?

Comment: The line that does return delegator.requestTwo highlights a compile error saying it excpets a Unit not a observable to be returned? If i remove the if statement, it can happily return another observable from the requestTwo

Comment: the saveSessionCookie needs to happen before i call the next request

Comment: You're actually using a non-local return. That is, either remove `return` entirely (the last line will be interpreted as a returned value) or use `return@flatMap`.

Comment: thanks that did the ttrick and got rid of that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit wierd that you need to call a callback inside `subscribe` method. Why do you need a **cb** if you already have **Rx**?. It'd be more clear if you return a `Single` and run your callback code where you actually subscribe:

```
...
// don't forget to handle the `disposable`
doSmth(requestData)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
            { success -> /* here's your success callback code */},
            { error -> /* handle error here */}
    )
...

fun doSmth(requestData: RequestData): Single<ResponseTwo> = delegator.requestOne(requestData)
        .doOnSuccess(::updateCookies)
        // you can extract the data you need from the first request using `it`
        .flatMap { delegator.requestTwo() }

fun updateCookies(response: Response<ResponseOne>) {
    val cookie = response.header(cookieStorage.COOKIE_HEADER_NAME)!!
    cookieStorage.saveSessionCookies(cookie)
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you still need a `callback`:

```
// don't forget to handle the `disposable`
delegator.requestOne(requestData)
        .doOnSuccess(::updateCookies)
        .flatMap { delegator.requestTwo() }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(
                { success -> callback.onSuccess(success) },
                { error -> callback.onError(error) }
        )

fun updateCookies(response: Response<ResponseOne>) {
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        val cookie = response.header(cookieStorage.COOKIE_HEADER_NAME)!!
        cookieStorage.saveSessionCookies(cookie)
    }
}
```

Comment: the cb is used in UI level whilst this bullk of code is inside a presenter doing the magic. it need the callbck from the ui as this code does not reside inside the ui class